# Listview show nothing with asynchronous method

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, asynchronous, widget

I don't know why when I build my project, no error are return but my `listview` is empty..

The class :

```
    final LocationService service = LocationService();
    late Future<List<Location>> _locations;

    @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _locations = service.getLocations();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Mes locations'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavBar(2),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<Location>>(
              future: _locations,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Location>> response) {
                List<Widget> children;
                if (response.hasData) {
                  children = <Widget>[
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: response.data?.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                        _BuildRow(response.data?[index]),
                      itemExtent: 285,
                    ),
                  ];
                } else if (response.hasError) {
                  children = <Widget>[
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.error_outline,
                      color: Colors.red,
                      size: 40,
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                      child: Text('Un problème est survenu'),
                    ),
                  ];
                } else {
                  children = const <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 6,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ];
                }
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: children,
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      );
    }

    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    _BuildRow(Location? location) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "OKOK",
                    style: LocationTextStyle.priceBoldGreyStyle,
                  ),
                  Text("${location?.dateFin}")
                ],
              ),
              Text("${location?.montanttotal}€")
            ],
          )
        ],
      );
    }
```

I have print my `response.data?.length` and it not empty.
At first it gave me the error "has size" but now the debug console is empty too...
You can find my project on GitLab : https://gitlab.com/victor.nardel/trash-project-flutter

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is caused by `ListView.builder`

simple solution:
wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded`

```
 if (response.hasData) {
       children = <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child:ListView.builder(
       ....
```

---

for better code:  just return the Widget, not List of widget.
something like below:

```
if(hasdata) return Listview();
else if(has error) return Column();
else return CircularIndicator();
```

so you can avoid redundant Widget.